# How Can I Tell the Day of the Week of a Date?

Tags: apex, formula, datetime, date

I'd like to build in some logic based on the weekday (e.g. Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday) of a given date.  How can I identify the date, using either formulas or Apex code?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

## Formulas

<del>There isn't a built-in function to do this for you, but you...</del> **UPDATE:** As of Spring 2018, there's a built-in function for this: `WEEKDAY()`.  It returns an integer where 1 is Sunday, 2 is Monday, 3 is Tuesday, etc.

## Apex Code

You could do the same thing with time deltas, but you can also use the poorly documented [DateTime.format() function](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm):

```
// Cast the Date variable into a DateTime
DateTime myDateTime = (DateTime) myDate;
String dayOfWeek = myDateTime.format('E');
// dayOfWeek is Sun, Mon, Tue, etc.
```

Comment: ditto @MikeChale, +1 for Datetime.format()

Comment: Re: Apex Code method: Will that always use the English abbreviations (Mon, Tue, Wed, etc.), or is it localized?  If localized, you wouldn't want to try converting the String to a number, or assume that a date is a weekend if it's "Sat" or "Sun".  In that case, an Apex version of the formula is a safer method.

Comment: +1 from me too, you have no idea how many times I had to tell my colleagues that `Date.toStartOfWeek()` gives Sunday for all these weird users with en_US locale ;) @tomlogic - yes, guaranteed to be always English.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but myDateTime.format('u') may be a better option -- it returns "Day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday)". According to the documentation. format() uses the locale of the current user, so I wouldn't want to bank on .format() always returning english words for days (if it does now, that may be "fixed" in the future).

Comment: One word of caution re casting the date to a datetime - you can end up on the wrong day and begin to question your sanity...you are better off doing a new instance and setting the time - see here for more details: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117163/datetime-day-returning-inconsistent-value#117163

Comment: Please note that casting a `Date` to a `Datetime` may introduce off-by-one errors due to time zone issues.

Answer (score 26):

Another alternative that avoids the pitfalls of `format()` returning locale specific values is to use the `daysBetween()` function between a known date and the comparison. (This is the apex equivalent to your formula)

For example the 1st Jan 1900 is a Monday, so the following code will give you the day of the week index with Monday being 0.

```
Math.mod(monday.daysBetween(dateValue), 7)
```

It is important to note that this will only work for days greater than the fixed date, the below assertions show this (the last assertion fails)

```
Date monday = Date.newInstance(1900, 1, 1);

Date wednesday = Date.newInstance(2012, 11, 14);
Date thursday = Date.newInstance(1900, 1, 4);
Date sunday7 = Date.newInstance(1900, 1, 7);

System.assertEquals(2, Math.mod(monday.daysBetween(wednesday), 7));
System.assertEquals(3, Math.mod(monday.daysBetween(thursday), 7));
System.assertEquals(6, Math.mod(monday.daysBetween(sunday7), 7));

//Date before the fixed monday, result is -3
System.assertEquals(4, Math.mod(sunday.daysBetween(Date.newInstance(1899, 12, 28)), 7));
```

Comment: Great solution to the this! Going to be handy knowing 1st Jan 1900 is a Monday!

Comment: This is great! Since Apex has Date and DateTime as different type. Would this be true for all timezones that 1st Jan 1990 is Monday?

Comment: @devilpreet Yes, since there is no time component, 1st Jan 1900 in Hawaii is just like 1st Jan 1900 in Australia.

Comment: Hello. The code is great. The monday should be changed to known sunday = Date.newInstance(1900, 1, 7);   - as from salesforce docs  https://blog.bessereau.eu/assets/pdfs/formula_date_time_tipsheet.pdf

Answer (score 16):

Since Apex uses Java's SimpleDateFormat, you can get the full name of the day of the week.

```
Date d = System.today();
Datetime dt = (DateTime)d;
String dayOfWeek = dt.format('EEEE'); //This returns - Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc..
```

Basically the same apex code as @Benj provided except the format part.
For a full list of supported formats, check [SimpleDateFormat Class][1]

Be careful when using format method as it converts to the local time zone of the context user, consider using formatGmt or format(dateFormat, timezone) if dealing with different timezones. For more information on this check [Apex Datetime Methods][2]

[1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html  [2]: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm

Comment: Your `SimpleDateFormat` link is a 404

Comment: This can provide misleading results in some cases.  Getting the date (without the time) and then converting to a datetime puts into GMT time.  Depending on your location and the time of day you run this, you can actually get the wrong day of the week.

Better to get the DateTime directly using System.now() and use that to get day of the week.

Answer (score 8):

For [SOQL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm) queries, you can use the `DAY_IN_WEEK()` Date Function.

Answer (score 7):

For reference, an Apex code version of the modular division approach is:

```
public static Integer dayOfWeekNumber(Date aDate) {
    return Math.mod(Date.newInstance(1900, 1, 7).daysBetween(aDate),7);
}
```

Sun = 0, Sat = 6

Comment: For what it's worth, formula syntax (not Apex) has now gained a WEEKDAY function. http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_field_formula_functions.htm#rn_forcecom_field_formula_functions

Answer (score 3):

I know all the answers are correct and enough, but I wanted to know this is also the way you can calculate the day of week. `Day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday)` for Date or Time Component. Please refer this : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for more info.

```
Date d = System.today();
Datetime dt = (DateTime)d;
String dayOfWeek = dt.format('u');
System.debug('~~~~~~~~~ ::'+dayOfWeek);
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than the modular division method, the most reliable and brief solution is this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(myDate, Time.newInstance(0,0,0,0));
String dayOfWeek = dt.format('u');
```

This assigns the numeric day of the week in String form (1=Monday, 2=Tuesday, ... , 7=Sunday) to dayOfWeek. If you simply cast to DateTime, the time zone adjustment will reach out and bite you.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified everything for myself from the examples below, maybe you will come in handy :)

```
public static Integer getWeekdayNumberFromDate(Date fromDate) {
    return Integer.valueOf(((Datetime) fromDate).format('u'));
}
```