# How to get day from Datetime field

Tags: apex, datetime

I want to extract my datetime value into different. I want to get day from the datetime value. eg: if datetime value is 2012/02/03 10:12:02 Tue. I want Tue from datetime. Is this possible.

Comment: In apex,Visualforce or a formula ?

Comment: in apex, i am trying to do it in my controller

Comment: Please check this existing answer out: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-can-i-tell-the-day-of-the-week-of-a-date

Comment: And why it's tagged salesforce-id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Datetime myDateTime = datetime.now();
System.debug(myDateTime.format('EEE'));
```

Outputs "Tue". Use "EEEE" for "Tuesday" (it will be always in English even if user's preferred language is different.