# DateTime Calculate in apex class

Tags: apex

how to display the following values from the two given date.

"IN"

```
  If does not contatain the Sunday or saturday.
```

"OUT"

```
   If Sunday or monday appear in the two give date.
```

Example:

indate :  20 - 9 -2014

Outdate: 21 - 9 -2014

Expected output:  Out (because the give date is contain the sunday)

Comment: I'm a bit cofused by this. If it was a Tuesday -> Saturday, would that be IN or OUT?

Comment: It should show both. I like this question.

Comment: Ok cool, I was a bit confused by the overlaps!

Answer (score 1):

You could build on the logic below to implement what you are looking for

```
public Boolean isSunday(Date d) {
    Integer dayOfWeek = Math.mod(Date.newInstance(1960, 1, 3).daysBetween(d), 7);
    // 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday...
    return dayOfWeek == 0;
}
```

The code uses a known Sunday to figure out the number of days between that date and the date you are comparing. It then does the `Math.mod` to find out the weekly offset from Sunday.

---

Another option would be to format the Date into the actual day, as shown below:

```
public Boolean isSunday(Date d) {
    String dayOfWeek = ((DateTime) d).format('EEEE');
    return dayOfWeek == 'Sunday';
}
```

Comment: is this applicable if we give the this monday to next monday?

Comment: Hi @Lemon, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Is this work,  if the Sunday contain in-between that two date?

Comment: This is not the solution to your problem, it is an example of how you can check a date to see if it's a particular day, so that you can build on this logic to implement your solution.

Comment: How to use  the loop for iterate the date?

Comment: You could do something like: `while (date1 <= date2) { // do something date1 = date1.addDays(1); }`

Answer (score 1):

So we can use this code ([as provided by Daniel Blackhall here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/4468/78)) to work out the day of the week (indexed from 0 for a monday to 6 for a Sunday):

```
Date monday = Date.newInstance(1900, 1, 1);
Integer firstDay = Math.mod(monday.daysBetween(date1), 7);
```

Which is quite useful when we want to check these rules out (assuming date1 comes before date2, swap if not!).

```
Integer first = Math.mod(monday.daysBetween(date1), 7);
Integer second = Math.mod(monday.daysBetween(date2), 7);

// Default to start
String output = 'IN';

// easy case, if there's six days or more between the dates, then it includes a Saturday and/or Sunday
if(date1.daysBetween(date2) >= 6)
{
  output = '';
}
else
{
  // less than a six days, so let's check the range
  if(first >=5 || second >= 5 || second < first)
  {
    output = '';
  }
}
```

So, right now, output will be "IN" if the range doesn't contain Saturday or Sunday. Now we can do the other part... again if there's more than 6 days then a Sunday or Monday must be included. Ff there isn't then it's a case of checking the day values if the first date is earlier in the week. If the dates wrap around then again, a Sunday or a Monday must be included.

```
if(date1.daysBetween(date2) >= 6)
{
  output += ' OUT';
}
else if(second > first && (first == 0 || second == 6)
{
  output += ' OUT';
}
else if(second < first)
{
  output += ' OUT';
}
```

Of coruse this could be condensed a little but I've left each test distinct to make it easier to read.

Comment: you have used the date.. but my value is datetime.. so please assign the monday value is datetime and let em know how can achieve?

Comment: It's basically identical... should be able to work it out from this!

Comment: Is this ittrate the date for checking every date?

Comment: Nope, because you don't need to check every date! You just need to check certain conditions about the range of dates.

Comment: you are using the date. but my value is date time. because if the cross the 8:30 on friday it should out off office so the output is out. how to implement that? I got issue form above code due to the datetime and date.

Comment: You need to edit your question to explain exactly what you need. You never mentioned time of day as being important to this. That said, you could still use the code I've written and then check the times at the end just to be sure.