# Hide column in pageBlockTable based on day

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

I have a pageBlockTable whose column headers are dynamically generated based on the date. I would like to hide any column whose date falls on a Sunday. Below is the sample of the code for one of the columns.

```
<apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">
        <apex:outputPanel >
            <apex:outputText value="{0, date, EEEE}">
                <apex:param value="{!NOW()}" />
            </apex:outputText>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!Appointment.Open__c}"/>
</apex:column>
```

Is it possible to set the rendered attribute of the column to the result of the boolean expression of whether the current day is Sunday?

Answer (score 1):

**VF route would be to do :**

```
<apex:column rendered="{!IF((MOD(DATEVALUE(TEXT(today())) - DATE(0001,1,1),7))==1,false,true)}"/>
```

**(OR)**

**IF you have a controller, get today's day using**

Reference : [How Can I Tell the Day of the Week of a Date?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-can-i-tell-the-day-of-the-week-of-a-date)

declare a boolean

```
public boolean rendercolumn{get;set;}
```

initialize in constructor

```
rendercolumn= true;
```

in your pageblocktable / datatable method add:

```
Date d = System.today();
Datetime dt = (DateTime)d;
String dayOfWeek = dt.format('EEEE');
if(dayofweek == "Sunday"){
rendercolumn = false;
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:column rendered="{!rendercolumn}">
```