# DateTime.day() returning inconsistent value when created from system.today()

Tags: apex, datetime

This came up on twitter from [@britishboyindc](https://twitter.com/britishboyindc/status/718170697076355072):

> Why does this return 'Wed'?

```
Date myDt = system.today();
DateTime myDtTime = (DateTime) myDt;
system.debug(myDtTime.format('E'));
```

For a user with the Pacific Standard Time `TimeZone` this is currently returning 'Wed' when it is Thursday.

I've also found the following assertion fails:

```
DateTime myDateTime = System.today();
System.assertEquals(myDateTime.day(), System.today().day());
```

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 6, Actual: 7

**Why does assigning the DateTime to a variable change the value?**

Comment: I suspect the issue is that `System.today()` returns a `Date`, not a `DateTime`. There is a conversion going on with the variable assignment that is losing the timezone details.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem was with initializing the `DateTime` variable by casting from a `Date`. As the Date had no Timezone information, the resulting DateTime was created at UTC+0. For Pacific Standard Time at the point of testing this put the current DateTime on the previous day.

Instead of directly casting the Date to a DateTime, the [DateTime.newInstance(date, time)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_newInstance_2) method should be used to construct the DateTime in the local time zone.

E.g. This will pass the assertion.

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(System.today(), Time.newInstance(0,0,0,0));
System.assertEquals(myDateTime.day(), System.today().day());
```

Comment: I had this problem in a test class. It would pass tests if run before 8PM EST, but would fail if run between 8 and midnight, because I was calculating the day differently in two places.